# javascript rotate what to change

Tags: javascript

I have ,

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var allArrows = $(".arrow"),
        arrowUpUrl = "select_arrow_up.png",
        arrowDownUrl = "select_arrow.png";

    allArrows.click(function () {
        var currentUrl = $(this).attr("src");

        $(this).attr("src", currentUrl === arrowDownUrl ? arrowUpUrl : arrowDownUrl);

        allArrows.not(this).attr("src", arrowDownUrl);
    });
});
```

my problem is when I click outside arrow do not return first position what I must change ?

i can't use css and toggle whit jquery I need to use images with outside place

http://jsfiddle.net/cYCnD/9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the following handler:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).hasClass('arrow')) {
        $('.arrow').attr('src', 'select_arrow.png');
    }
});
```

See my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cYCnD/10/

The whole code should look like this:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var allArrows = $(".arrow"),
    arrowUpUrl = "select_arrow_up.png",
    arrowDownUrl = "select_arrow.png";

    allArrows.click(function () {
        var currentUrl = $(this).attr("src");

        $(this).attr("src", currentUrl === arrowDownUrl ? arrowUpUrl : arrowDownUrl);

        allArrows.not(this).attr("src", arrowDownUrl);
    });

    $(document).on('click', function(e) {
        if (!$(e.target).hasClass('arrow')) {
            allArrows.attr('src', 'select_arrow.png');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: ok this is what I'm looking for
but when paste in my code i have 
communique allArrows is not defined

Comment: sorry my fault :) 
i have class .select_arrow not only .arrow :) 
great 
all it's working :)
thnx

Comment: I just added the whole code that you should use, just for reference.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to reset the arrows positions when a user clicks elsewhere on the page.

If so, I believe this will work:

```
 $(document).click(function(e){
    if(!$(e.target).hasClass('arrow'))
         $(".arrow").attr("src", select_arrow.png)
 });
```

Comment: i need something without class
only directly images no background class 
something like my first link 
who knows ?